# Problem creating a table with dynamic column cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I'm creating a table component with dynamic cells and columns, the header works fine, but I'm having trouble with the rows, I can't get them to render correctly.

I want to be able to do this so that I can reuse this component in different places in my application, and not have to write all the code for the table in other components.

What am I doing wrong?

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map') The

> above error occurred in the  component:

I don't understand why it gives me a `key` warning if I'm sending the `index` to each component

**Company Page**

```js
import DataTable from "../components/DataTable";

const CompanyPage = function () {
  const headers = [
    "id",
    "Company Name",
    "Alias",
    "R.N.C.",
  ];

  const Data_fromAPI = [
    {
      id: 1,
      cn: "Comany Name ABC",
      a: "Alias ABC",
      rnc: "123456789",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      cn: "Comany Name DFG",
      a: "Alias DFG",
      rnc: "987654321",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      cn: "Comany Name HYJ",
      a: "Alias HYJ",
      rnc: "112233456",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <DataTable Headers={headers} Data={Data_fromAPI} />
    </>
  );
};
export default CompanyPage;
```

DataTable

```js
import {
  Table,
  TableContainer,
  Tbody,
  Td,
  Th,
  Thead,
  Tr,
} from "./DataTableStyled";

const DataTable = function ({ Headers, Data }) {
  // Dinamic Head
  const HeadItem = function ({ item, index }) {
    return <Th key={index}>{item}</Th>;
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <Thead>
          <Tr>
            {Headers.map((head, i) => (
              <HeadItem item={head} index={i} />
            ))}
          </Tr>
        </Thead>
        <Tbody>
          {Data.map((row, index) => (
            <Tr key={index}>
              {Headers.map((head) => (
                <Td>{row[head]}</Td>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
export default DataTable;
```

**CSS**

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const TableContainer = styled.div`
  overflow-x: auto;
`;

export const TableBase = css`
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
`;

export const Table = styled.table`
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
`;

export const Thead = styled.thead``;
export const Th = styled.th`
  ${TableBase}
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: #00aea9;
  color: whitesmoke;
`;
export const Tr = styled.tr`
  &:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
`;
export const Td = styled.td`
  ${TableBase}
`;
export const Tbody = styled.tbody``;
export const Tfoot = styled.tfoot``;
```

Error:
[image]

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/browse/styled-components@5.3.5/dist/styled-components.cjs.js.map"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Td>` needs a key prop.

```
{Headers.map((head) => (
  <Td>{row[head]}</Td> // key here.
))}
```

I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cache-3hb4g5?file=/src/DataTable.js) with your code (normal html table) & set `key` to a random integer. Warning is gone.

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
...
<tbody>
      {Data.map((row, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          {Headers.map((head) => (
            <td key={getRandomInt(100000)}>{row[head]}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
</tbody>
```

Not able to reproduce rest of the two errors.

**Edit**: Rest of the columns are not displaying data as the headers don't match the data properties. Update `headers` to ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cache-3hb4g5?file=/src/DataTable.js) is updated) -

```
const headers = ["id", "cn", "a", "rnc"];
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it also had a `key`.
One question, why are the rest of my cells not rendered? company name, alias, r.c.n ..

Comment: @I'mnewbie Updated answer. `headers` don't match data props. You can now see all column data. Can accept this as answer.